# How can I position views on devices with and without on screen buttons in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am using a relative layout to display my main UI. In this layout I have got 3 buttons at the bottom. It basically looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Some other content  ... -->

<!-- These are the 3 buttons at the bottom -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:src="@drawable/button1" />

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:src="@drawable/button2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/button3"
    android:src="@drawable/button3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, what I also do in my app is using a full screen layout (like the way featured in Android KitKat). This means that the UI flows behind the navigation bar/ On-Screen-Buttons.

What I try to achieve is this:

- **For devices that have got on screen buttons:**
  The 3 buttons should be positioned right above the On-Screen-Buttons:
- **For devices that don't have on screen buttons:**
  The 3 buttons should be positioned right at the bottom of the screen.

Any ideas how to do this? Can I use `fitSystemWindows`?

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple. Use a FrameLayout, the first child will be your app ui inside of a LinearLayout. The second child will be your app button bar inside a LinearLayout. We will use weighting to make sure the button bar is always at the bottom of the devices screen.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/regularLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actualButtonBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You'll need to rewrite your question for me to help you further.

Comment: What information do you need? your layout simply does not achieve what I described in my problem